# Copying and exporting chat from Zoom

Tags: copy-and-paste, zoom-meeting

Is there a way of selection on Zoom under Ubuntu all the chat to copy and paste it into  a text file? I can only select one message at a time.

Comment: +1 This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the answer by @MinseonShin. If the host of the meeting allows it, you can save the chat by clicking in the Zoom chat window the "`...`" icon, then "Save Chat", otherwise it seems not be possible. Then you should see a link to "Show in Folder".

If that doesn't work, the path in my case is `~/Document/Zoom/<date+someinfo>/`, for @MinseonShin it was because of using snap `~/snap/zoom-client/<something>/Documents/Zoom/<date+someinfo>/` where something was `166` or `167`.

If your installation is different, you find about the path as follows: you start a meeting (eg. using the personal meeting id) and record the meeting to your computer (not on the cloud), and then save recording and stop it. Now under **Zoom > meetings > recorded**  you can find that recorded meeting. If you open it it opens a folder with that particular meeting. The meeting with the chat will not appear in the list of recorded meetings (unless you recorded it as well), but if you go up one directory you see all recorded meetings including the one where you saved the chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the chat by clicking (in the Zoom chat window) the "..." icon, then "Save Chat"; then you should see a link to "Show in Folder", which is not working for me today for some reason -- it turns out that (on Ubuntu 20.04) the files are saved (in .txt format) in `~/snap/zoom-client/[###]/Documents/Zoom/[meeting date, time, name]`. For me the `[###]` part is `166` or `167` but I could not figure out what it meant so I thought it may be different for different people. (See also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1546578/how-can-i-access-saved-whiteboards-in-zoom).)